# Abnormal behaviour of JavaScript with checkbox

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I used the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function doit(page) {
        var entry = page.entry;
        var flag = false;
        document.write(entry.length);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <span id="error_checkbox" style="color: blue;"> </span>
    <form name="subscribeTablePage">
        <input type="checkbox" id="entry" value="1"/> <label>1</label><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="doit(document.subscribeTablePage)"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is the value of `entry.length` undefined? At the same time when I tried with multiple checkboxes, the value of `entry.length` was the number of checkboxes used!

Use Case :
I am going to retrieve rows from Database and in that case I need to check the number of checkboxes checked to perform deletion operation !! Please give ur valuable comments to sort this problem

Comment: If you want to count the number of charachters of each checkbox you have to do it like this: `document.write(entry.value.length)`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the checkbox `#entry`. add the attribute `name="entry"` like so.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="entry" name="entry" value="1" />
```

Form objects are accessed by their `name` property.

As for the Javascript, you want `value`, not `length`.

```
document.write(entry.value);
```

`length` represents the length in characters of a given string.

Comment: Austin Brunkhorst, the out put remains undefined even after trying it with
<input type="checkbox" name="entry" id="entry" value="1"/>

Comment: Please give ur valuable suggestion !!

Answer (score 0):

`entry` is `id` of your `input`
it should be `name` if you want to refer it in that way..

```
<input type="checkbox" name="entry" id="entry" value="1"/>
```

To access it form element by id you have to use

```
document.getElementById('idOfElement')
```

Also I dont find your objective for using length. you can get `size` of the `input` not `length`.

If you want to find number of checkboxes checked then probably in javascript you can check by writing a script as below

```
var inputElems = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    count = 0;
for (var i=0; i<inputElems.length; i++) {
    if (inputElems[i].type === "checkbox" && inputElems[i].checked === true) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually my use case is different. I will be retrieving rows from database and there could be any number of row entries !!

Comment: @Nandhan - so what do you want to achieve using `length`?

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion :) I shall check and see the output.

Comment: But could you please tell, why the entry.length in mycase was giving the output as undefined if there are oly one checkbox ??

Comment: @Nandhan - well `length` is not the property of `input` element. If you have more then one `checkbox` it forms a `array` and thus it gives you the result of length, or if you try to get `length` of `value` it would be possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the value of entry.length undefined?

Because `form.entry` references the element, and the element doesn't have a length property. You want:

```
entry.value.length;
```

> At the same time when I tried with multiple checkboxes, the value of entry.length was the number of checkboxes used!

Because if more than one form control has the same name, `form.controlName` references a collection of all the controls with the same name. [HTML Collections](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-75708506) have a length property that is the number of elements in the collection.

Also, the line:

```
>       document.write(entry.length);
```

will clear the entire document, likely you want:

```
 alert(entry.value.length);

 // or

 console.log(entry.value.length);
```

You may find it useful to read the entire section about forms in the [HTML 5 specification](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/forms.html#forms), and also relevant parts of the [HTML 4.01 standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#form-controls).